# Ask another server to resolve a domain name?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm writing a tool that checks against various ADs to see if a user's assigned accounts are locked out on any of the various separate AD's domain controllers.

However, every built in object provided by the .NET ad libraries seems to only resolve locally or never hand back an IP - even when using ldap via ip.

Is there a method I can call that will ask an arbitrary remote server to resolve a domain name to an ip?

```
resolver (serverIp, creds, hostnameToResolve) {
Asks serverIp if it can map hostnameToResolve to an ip
returns ip
}
```

Comment: You mean something like a `DNS`?

Comment: @Hackerman The dns object doesn't appear to have a way to query an arbitrary remote server to resolve to an IP. It appears to just walk up the local resolution stack.

Comment: DNS protocol is simple, so you can even construct your own DNS query packets, and send to the target server.

Comment: @LexLi Do you have any examples you could link to or show?

Comment: If you ask Google, then such is at the first page, https://github.com/kapetan/dns/blob/master/README.md